# Who is the giant hologram in a chair?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

In *The Force Awakens* who is the hologram lord guy whom the Dark Side soldiers and captains consult? He’s in a chair like that US president, and is a hologram, and is gigantic as well as old and alien like looking. Sort of like Voldemort.

Does the film explain who he is?

Comment: When typing that in it didn't suggest that it had already been asked. Why he 3 down votes?

Comment: Even before typing a question it's best to search around to see if it's been asked before. For example, if you simply search "kylo and hux" the first result is the question you were looking for. That said, [duplicate questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) aren't a bad thing, in fact they can be a good thing as the different wording can sometimes help people find the anser they're looking for. Sadly however, _some_ users downvote questions for being a dupe. There's no way to know for sure why they DVed unless they also comment. +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Snoke. He is the new grandmaster: the “emperor” of the Sith. He is Kylo Ren’s mentor and supreme leader of the First Order.

There are very few theories about Snoke’s past.

He might be Darth Plagueis, Palpatine’s master, and have survived from his overthrow by Palpatine, since Plagueis could change the midi-chlorians into forms of life.

Snoke could also be Palpatine. Somehow Palpatine could have survived when he was picked up and thrown by Vader into the shaft.
(That could be why Snoke is deformed and scarred.)
He comes back and changes his identity. He appears big in holograms just like he does for Vader. (Empire Strikes Back)

Answer (score 3):

He is Supreme Leader Snoke.  Like the title suggests, he is in charge of the whole 'First Order'.